# Why do I have to return a view in onCreateView instead of setting the view directly?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am a little confuse about the method

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState).
```

1) I am not so sure why a fragment has to used this code in order to link it with a view or xml file.

2) Why can't I call setContentView() directly in a fragment instead of going through onCreateView() method and return a view object.

3) What method or object is taking in this return View as a parameter?

Comment: Possibly for caching, since fragment views can be recreated more frequently than Activity views?

Comment: Thanks for answering I appreciated it  but I would like a more definitive answer.

Comment: Yeah, if I had a more definitive source I'd add it as an actual answer :) One other thing I thought of: in `onCreateView` you must explicitly return `null` to indicate that your `Fragment` has no view hierarchy (as opposed to just _not calling_ the analog of `setContentView`). Perhaps this also allows for some framework optimizations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) I am not so sure why a fragment has to used this code in order to
>   link it with a view or xml file.

This code will return a view that is used to display what you want on your layout.
the Fragment has this method but you override with with your own layout, container and bundle if needed. How do you override it? with what you return in the method.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.somelayout, container, false)
```

> 2) Why can't I call setContentView() directly in a fragment instead of
>   going through onCreateView() method and return a view object.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
}
```

Another reason is because onCreate in activity must be protected whereas onCreateView is public because fragments need to communicate with each other. I.e. you can't use setContentView on multiple fragments because onCreate is protected.

> 3) What method or object is taking in this return View as a parameter?

The lifecycle of a fragment is controlled by the `FragmentManager`, 
[image: Lifecycle of a Fragment]

When you add the fragment to the stack, its view is called by the `FragmentManager` to see what is required to be put on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to what I could guess based on the code,

FragmentActivity:

```
final FragmentController mFragments = FragmentController.createController(new HostCallbacks());

@Override
final View dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context,
        AttributeSet attrs) {
    return mFragments.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
}
```

FragmentController:

```
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    return mHost.mFragmentManager.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
}
```

FragmentManagerImpl:

```
final class FragmentManagerImpl extends FragmentManager implements LayoutInflaterFactory {
//[...]
void moveToState(Fragment f, int newState, int transit, int transitionStyle,
        boolean keepActive) {
     //[...]
            if (f.mFromLayout) {
                    // For fragments that are part of the content view
                    // layout, we need to instantiate the view immediately
                    // and the inflater will take care of adding it.
                    f.mView = f.performCreateView(f.getLayoutInflater(
                            f.mSavedFragmentState), null, f.mSavedFragmentState);
                    if (f.mView != null) {
                        f.mInnerView = f.mView;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                            ViewCompat.setSaveFromParentEnabled(f.mView, false);
                        } else {
                            f.mView = NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(f.mView);
                        }
                        if (f.mHidden) f.mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        f.onViewCreated(f.mView, f.mSavedFragmentState);
                    } else {
                        f.mInnerView = null;
                    }
                }
               //[...]
                   if (!f.mFromLayout) {
                        ViewGroup container = null;
                        if (f.mContainerId != 0) {
                            container = (ViewGroup)mContainer.onFindViewById(f.mContainerId);
                            if (container == null && !f.mRestored) {
                                throwException(new IllegalArgumentException(
                                        "No view found for id 0x"
                                        + Integer.toHexString(f.mContainerId) + " ("
                                        + f.getResources().getResourceName(f.mContainerId)
                                        + ") for fragment " + f));
                            }
                        }
                        f.mContainer = container;
                        f.mView = f.performCreateView(f.getLayoutInflater(
                                f.mSavedFragmentState), container, f.mSavedFragmentState);
                        if (f.mView != null) {
                            f.mInnerView = f.mView;
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
                                ViewCompat.setSaveFromParentEnabled(f.mView, false);
                            } else {
                                f.mView = NoSaveStateFrameLayout.wrap(f.mView);
                            }
                            if (container != null) {
                                Animation anim = loadAnimation(f, transit, true,
                                        transitionStyle);
                                if (anim != null) {
                                    setHWLayerAnimListenerIfAlpha(f.mView, anim);
                                    f.mView.startAnimation(anim);
                                }
                                container.addView(f.mView);
                            }
                            if (f.mHidden) f.mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            f.onViewCreated(f.mView, f.mSavedFragmentState);
                        } else {
                            f.mInnerView = null;
                        }
                    }

                    f.performActivityCreated(f.mSavedFragmentState);
                    if (f.mView != null) {
                        f.restoreViewState(f.mSavedFragmentState);
                    }
                    f.mSavedFragmentState = null;
       ...

void saveFragmentViewState(Fragment f) {
    if (f.mInnerView == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (mStateArray == null) {
        mStateArray = new SparseArray<Parcelable>();
    } else {
        mStateArray.clear();
    }
    f.mInnerView.saveHierarchyState(mStateArray);
    if (mStateArray.size() > 0) {
        f.mSavedViewState = mStateArray;
        mStateArray = null;
    }
}
```

Let's just say that the fragment manager needs to see the view directly in order to manage the fragment's internal state. Fragments are confusing, so I haven't conclusively figured it out.